# Github page not working completely --error

Tags: github

Github page not working completely

I've created my github.io page but it's graphics are not loading completely and browser display a warning: opera has blocked content of this page which comes from insecure sources.

How to fix this?

my github page:https://perk-bevis.github.io/bibimobile.com.vn/
repo link:https://github.com/perk-bevis/bibimobile.com.vn